# Error encountered during startup Cassandra 3.11.2

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am getting a new error while starting the Cassandra as org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid value ??PERCENTILE for option 'speculative_retry'

I am using apache cassandra 3.11.2 on Windows 10 Pro. Please let me know if there is any possible solution.

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid value ??PERCENTILE for option 'speculative_retry'
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid value ??PERCENTILE for option 'speculative_retry'
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SpeculativeRetryParam.fromString(SpeculativeRetryParam.java:113)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.createTableParamsFromRow(SchemaKeyspace.java:1082)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:1059)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:998)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:957)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:934)
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:922)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:82)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:262)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691)
ERROR [main] 2019-07-02 14:47:39,401 CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid value ??PERCENTILE for option 'speculative_retry'
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SpeculativeRetryParam.fromString(SpeculativeRetryParam.java:113) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.createTableParamsFromRow(SchemaKeyspace.java:1082) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTable(SchemaKeyspace.java:1059) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchTables(SchemaKeyspace.java:998) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:957) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:934) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:922) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:262) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
```

Comment: What method of installation did you use for Cassandra?

Comment: It's a tarball extracted from apache-cassandra-3.11.2-bin.tar folder. I am starting cassandra from 'C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.2\bin' path by running cassandra.bat through command prompt which I always do on different machines but never come across such error.
I tested the same setup on another machine and it runs fine but not able to resolve this error on the machine I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined speculative_retry in your table creation statement(s) in a way that doesn't match the required format.

Example formats that are acceptable (if a number, has to be between 0.0 and 100.0):

```
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

OR

```
AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

Check what you have configured for your tables in the schema.

Comment: Thanks for the update Valerie. But I have not created any table or schema yet. This is a fresh installation of Apache Cassandra on new PC and just trying to start the Cassandra.